# Pytorch CNN loss is not changing,

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I making a CNN for a binary classification problem between bees and ants images. 
Images are of 500x500 dimension with 3 channels.

Here is my code.

**Dataloader:**

```
def load_data(path):
    data = []
    ant = 0
    bee = 0
    for folder in os.listdir(path):
        print(folder)
        curfolder = os.path.join(path, folder)
        for file in os.listdir(curfolder):
            image = plt.imread(curfolder+'/'+file)
            image = cv2.resize(image, (500,500))
            if folder == 'ants':
                ant += 1
                data.append([np.array(image) , np.eye(2)[0]])
            elif folder == 'bees':
                bee += 1
                data.append([np.array(image) , np.eye(2)[1]])

    np.random.shuffle(data)      
    np.save('train.npy',data)
    print('ants : ',ant)
    print('bees : ',bee)

training_data = np.load("train.npy",allow_pickle=True)
print(len(training_data))
```

**CNN class**

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # just run the init of parent class (nn.Module)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5) # input is 1 image, 32 output channels, 5x5 kernel / window
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5) # input is 32, bc the first layer output 32. Then we say the output will be 64 channels, 5x5 kernel / window
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5)

        x = torch.randn(3,500,500).view(-1,3,500,500)
        self._to_linear = None
        self.convs(x)
        print(self._to_linear)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 512) #flattening.
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 2) # 512 in, 2 out bc we're doing 2 classes (dog vs cat).

    def convs(self, x):
        # max pooling over 2x2
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2, 2))

        if self._to_linear is None:
            self._to_linear = x[0].shape[0]*x[0].shape[1]*x[0].shape[2]
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convs(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self._to_linear)  # .view is reshape ... this flattens X before 
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x) # bc this is our output layer. No activation here.
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)

net = Net()
print(net)
```

**loss and optimizer**

```
import torch.optim as optim

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
```

**Data Flat**

```
train_X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in training_data]).view(-1,3,500,500)
train_X = train_X/255.0
train_y = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in training_data])
```

**training the model**

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
net = Net().to(device)
print(len(train_X))
epochs = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 1
for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i in range(0, len(train_X), BATCH_SIZE): # from 0, to the len of x, stepping BATCH_SIZE at a time. [:50] ..for now just to dev
            #print(f"{i}:{i+BATCH_SIZE}")
            batch_X = train_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]
            batch_y = train_y[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]

            batch_X, batch_y = batch_X.to(device), batch_y.to(device)
            net.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(batch_X)
            loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()     # Does the update

        print(f"Epoch : {epoch}. Loss: {loss}")
```

The loss does not update for every epoch. I have tried changing the learning rate but the problem still remains.

> Epoch : 0. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 1. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 2. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 3. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 4. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 5. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 6. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 7. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 8. Loss: 0.23345321416854858
>
> Epoch : 9. Loss: 0.23345321416854858

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a comment. In my personal experience, training a classifier with images bigger than 256x256 is not going to improve as much the classification accuracy, and model will take much; much more time. I would only use big images for instance segmentation, not classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your training loop, you should do `optimizer.zero_grad()` instead of `net.zero_grad()`. Also, you are using `MSELoss()` for a classification problem, you need something like `BinaryCrossEntropy()` or `CrossEntropy()` or `NLLLoss()`.

Comment: Yes, you must be right. Can you tell me how to deal with this problem? 

RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'target' in call to _thnn_nll_loss_forward. 

I got this error at line 
loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y), after I changed the loss function CrossEntropy()

Comment: Cast your labels to long (like `labels = labels.long()`) before passing to loss function. Also, be sure that your labels don't have negative values (that will break the working of those loss functions, check the docs for more information).

Comment: @ahsanmukhtar If this answered your question, then click the green tick mark so that the question can be closed (as answered). For any further questions, you can ask a separate question.